# Is it possible to wrap and properly align inline comments?

Tags: vimrc, wrapping

```
set textwidth=60
let &colorcolumn=&textwidth
set linebreak
```

Is there a relatively simple way (that is, with using `formatoptions` only) to make Vim format inline comments (`gq`) from this:

```
this_is_some_statement  // and this is an inline comment, which I want to be wrapped
```

to this:?

```
this_is_some_statement  // and this is an inline comment,
                        // which is wrapped properly
```

Currently, it wraps it to

```
this_is_some_statement  // and this is an inline comment,
the second line of which is not even a comment
```

Edit: Well, okay, it seems it is not possible with `formatoptions` only. If someone could help with a more complex solution, this will be great. Currently I'm going to try to write such a function myself...

Comment: You could probably get part of the way by looking for `&l:commentstring` on the line, but that is sometimes set to use multi-line instead of single-line comments. At this point I usually do `DO<esc>pgqq` (or `D[pgqq` with unimpaired)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long comments should precede the code, not follow it. Misuse of "inline" comments is a remarkably bad style.

However, Vim is able to format such comments. This is due to `&cindent` option which is usually on for C files after standard `filetype indent on` command. So this is almost by default.

Comment: `If 'indentexpr' is not empty, it overrules 'cindent'` -> that was the first problem

Comment: @r_31415 C-like languages, such as Java, may use `cindent()` as a "last resort" for custom `&indentexpr` procedure. Then this feature will work, of course. But if a language is not even close to C then it all depends on a specific implementation of `GetIndentXXX()` function.

Comment: Interesting. From what I know, `GetIndentXXX()` usually works well, but it gets in the way when a different formatting is needed, even for languages with C-like syntax.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the help, though I still don't understand how to make it work, for example, for JavaScript...

Comment: @johnc.j. Current implementation of `GetJavascriptIndent()` does not support this.